# O-ring dataset with thickness, Shore hardness, and diameter

Tags: data-request

I am looking for an o-ring dataset containing as many following fields as possible:

- o-ring model name and manufacturer
- thickness
- Shore hardness
- diameter (inner and outer)

I am only interested in o-ring that can be used in keyboards.

---

Some terminology:

Shore hardness:

[image]

Diameter (inner and outer):

[image]